# Push-уведомления в ASP.NET 5 проекте с помощью SignalR 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Как реализовать push-уведомления в ASP.NET 5 проекте, в котором используются MVC 6 и .NET Core? Нужно использовать SignalR 3 (можно что-то взамен).

Comment: ну так у вас в вопросе содержится ответ: чтобы реализовать push-уведомления - используйте signalR

Comment: либо можно что-то взамен